# How to split an Array based on conditions using anonymous function

Tags: javascript

I have an array list with application name (app1, app2, etc) and related ID's as showed below:

```
["App1|380d82838f", "App1|54870d82838f", "App2|882538011", "App2|82538011", "App2|82567845"]
```

and I need to re-write the array with unique application name and with all the respective ID's separated by "|".

```
["App1|380d82838f-54870d82838f", "App2|882538011-82538011-82567845"]
```

any directions greatly appreciated.

thanks
Alex

Comment: Are those supposed to be strings?

Comment: yes, they are strings.

Comment: Is this your actual code?  Why aren't they in quotes?

Answer (score 1):

You could take an object for collectiong and take the entries for mapping the result;

```js
const
    data = ['App1|380d82838f', 'App1|54870d82838f', 'App2|882538011', 'App2|82538011', 'App2|82567845'],
    result = Object
        .entries(data.reduce(function (r, s) {
            const [key, value] = s.split('|');
            (r[key] = r[key] || []).push(value);
            return r;
        }, {}))
        .map(function (a) { return a.join('|'); });

console.log(result);
```

Comment: it is giving me "yntax error (null.null.script; line 4) in:"

Comment: I found out that my custom javascript editor does not support Arrow function, so I need to swap the arrow function with anonymous functions.

Answer (score 0):

```
var data = ["App1|380d82838f","App1|54870d82838f","App2|882538011","App2|82538011","App2|82567845"]

const output = data.reduce((out, item) => {
  const parts = item.split("|");
  const existing = out.find(el =>  el.startsWith(parts[0]));

  if (existing) out[out.indexOf(existing)] += "-" + parts[1];
  else out.push(parts.join("|"))

  return out;
}, []);

console.log(output); // [ "App1|380d82838f-54870d82838f", "App2|882538011-82538011-82567845" ]
```

Comment: it is giving me this error "Javascript compiler exception: syntax error (null.null.script; line 2) in:"

Comment: maybe depends on your environment, you can play around with it here https://jsfiddle.net/douck09w/

Comment: I found out that my custom javascript editor does not support Arrow function, so I need to swap the arrow function with anonymous functions.